# what is the difference between webhook client and action-on-google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a question about the Dialogflow node js code.
There are two different way to build an intent in code :

- with the **webhook client**
- with **action on google**

the code has a form like :

app.intent(....) with conv.ask or a basic function with agent.add(...) .

Comment: It *sounds* like you're asking what the difference is between two different libraries for Dialogflow? Is that correct? You've posted single lines of code - can you post longer examples

Comment: @Prisoner check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081444/no-handler-for-requested-intent-at-webhookclient-handlerequest

Comment: @Midhilaj - That question was deleted. Was it related to this question in some way?

Comment: @Prisoner I got the solution and I removed my comment. Thank you for supporting